# display the datas per user

Tags: php, sql

I want to display the data per user.
But it displays all the data per table and per users.
So what I am trying to achieve is display all the data on the table for that user
here is my code

```
<?php foreach ($employee as $emp) { ?>

  <table id="employee-content">
     <h3 class="color-orange"><?php echo $emp['members']['username']; ?></h3>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="personal-management-content"><?php echo $emp['posts']['title']; ?></p></td>
          <td><p class="personal-management-content padding-left50" class="padding-left50"><?php echo $emp['posts']['title']; ?></p></td>
          <td><p class="personal-management-content padding-left50" class="padding-left50"><?php echo $emp['posts']['deadline']; ?></p></td>
        </tr>

<?php } ?>'
```

here is the sql query for $employee

```
* on controller 
   public function employee_management() {
        $posts = $this->Post->getPostByMember();
        $this->set("employee", $posts);
    }

* on model
    public function getPostByMember() {
        $post = "SELECT username, content, deadline, title FROM members INNER JOIN posts ON posts.member_id=members.id";
//        debug($user);
        $con = $this->getDataSource();
        $get = $con->fetchAll($post);
//        debug($get);
        return $get;
    }
```

and the print_r $employee

```
Array (
 [0] => Array (
   [members] => Array (
     [username] => admin )
   [posts] => Array (
     [content] => asdsadsad
     [deadline] => 2012-06-01
     [title] => sad ) ) 
 [1] => Array (
   [members] => Array (
     [username] => admin )
   [posts] => Array (
     [content] => asd
     [deadline] => 2012-06-20
     [title] => sad ) ) 
 [2] => Array (
   [members] => Array (
     [username] => admin )
   [posts] => Array (
     [content] => dasdw2
     [deadline] => 2012-06-19
     [title] => sdas ) ) 
 [3] => Array (
   [members] => Array (
     [username] => guest )
   [posts] => Array (
     [content] => s
     [deadline] => 2012-06-08
     [title] => wara ) )
```

the output is 
sample screen shot
http://i46.tinypic.com/209n56s.jpg

so what I want to achieve is 
for example the user "admin" all his titles, descriptions, deadlines will show on the single box or the .
And so goes to the other users.

please help thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  What is your question?  Please [edit what you've posted](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11200420/edit) and provide more detail.

Comment: @ghoti sorry about that, the post has been edited

Comment: ① Add your SQL that populates the $employee array.  ② Show a `print_r($employee)` so we know what your data actually look like.  ③ Fix your HTML.  Your sample code starts multiple tables, embeds a `<h3>` in the wrong place and finishes none of them. Obvious structural errors that get in the way of debugging the code you haven't included in your question.  You will get the best responses if you provide enough code that people answering can actually reproduce your problem on their own systems.

Comment: @ghoti as you requested. If you still need something please do reply, thanks

Comment: It's improving!  But as far as I can tell, you still have some severe HTML structural issues that will corrupt your output even if your query is correct. I can't tell whether your question is about fixing your HTML or fixing your SQL, but neither of those was how you tagged your question.  You tagged your question [tag:php].  Which of these technologies are you actually having trouble with?  All of them, as your question suggests, or is further clarification required?

Comment: @ghoti thanks for your reply. I posted a screen shot above. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So...  It looks like your database results are currently structured like this:

- result 1

  - username 1
  - post
- result 2

  - username 1
  - post
- result 3

  - username 2

etc.  And you want your display to look like:

- username 1

  - post
  - post
- username 2

  - post

It seems to me that the easiest way to achieve what you want is to create a new array from the results of your SELECT.

```
<?php

$posts_by_emp=array();
foreach ($employee as $emp) {
  $posts_by_emp[$emp['members']['username']][]=array(
    'title' => $emp['posts']['title'];
    'descr' => $emp['posts']['title'];
    'deadline' => $emp['posts']['deadline']
  );
}

$hfmt = "<tr>\n    <th colspan='3' class='color-orange'>%s</th>\n  </tr>";
$bfmt = "<tr>\n"
      . "    <td class='personal-management-content'>%s</td>\n"
      . "    <td class='personal-management-content padding-left50'>%s</td>\n"
      . "    <td class='personal-management-content padding-left50'>%s</td>\n"
      . "  </tr>";

print "  <table id='employee-content'>";
foreach ($posts_by_emp as $username => $items) {
  // Print header
  printf($hfmt, $username);
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    // Print post
    printf($bfmt, $item['title'], $item['descr'], $item['deadline']);
  }
}
print "</table>\n";
```

This is of course untested, because I don't have your data.  Depending on the structure of your database, you might be able to do this with less PHP by making a different SQL query that could be parsed more easily.